# Function to sum cells by color

Tags: excel, vba, background-color

Below I placed a function code to sum cells by color. I wrote a sub to execute the function.

I get a Run-time '1004' error. I don't know what part is causing the error. I can't see the issue.

```vb
    Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    If SUM = True Then
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
            End If
        Next rCell
    Else
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

    ColorFunction = vResult
    End Function

    Sub sumbycolor()

    NextRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 9
    Range("B" & NextRow).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Dim lr As Long, critRange As String, sumRange As String
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
    sumRange = Range("O2:O" & lr).Address

    CellColor = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 9

    NextRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 9
    Range("C" & NextRow).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ColorFunction(" & CellColor & "," & sumRange & ",TRUE)"

    End Sub
```

Comment: For one, you are passing integer `CellColor` in this statement: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ColorFunction(" & CellColor & "," & sumRange & ",TRUE)"`, where the function expects a Range. Double check the data types that you put into the formula to call the function.

Comment: Aha, I also just noticed you're using `FormulaR1C1` but passing sumRange in "A1" style notation. Use `ActiveCell.Formula=...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a code snippet that incorporates changes I mentioned in my comments to your question. I created a string to hold the formula for ease in debugging.

```
...
Dim lr As Long, critRange As String, sumRange As String
Dim intCellColorRow As Integer
Dim strCellColorRange As String
Dim strFormula As String

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
sumRange = Range("O2:O" & lr).Address

intCellColorRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 9
strCellColorRange = Range("B" & intCellColorRow).Address

NextRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 9
Range("C" & NextRow).Select
strFormula = "=ColorFunction(" & strCellColorRange & "," & sumRange & ",TRUE)"
ActiveCell.Formula = strFormula
...
```